# Add link to OpenShift console's application selector

Tags: console, openshift

I've noticed that installing the `openshift-gitops` operator in ArgoCD also adds a link to Argo in the console's application(?) menu. Is there a way I can add my own links to this menu?

[image: openshift console with application list expanded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just researched this myself - you need to make a ConsoleLink resource following the instructions here:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/web_console/customizing-the-web-console.html#creating-custom-links_customizing-web-console

Here's an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: console.openshift.io/v1
kind: ConsoleLink
metadata:
  name: application-menu-link-1
spec:
  href: 'https://www.example.com'
  location: ApplicationMenu
  text: Link 1
  applicationMenu:
    section: My New Section
    # image that is 24x24 in size
    imageURL: https://via.placeholder.com/24
```